# What is the difference between assignment and creating object

Tags: java, string, integer, variable-assignment

Lets say we do

```
String s=new String ("test");
String s="test";
```

And

```
Integer i=new Integer(10);
Integer i=10;
```

What is the difference ?

Comment: In your example, very little.  Maybe ask the question, what's the difference between being handed a baby and giving birth

Comment: I dnt understand this . Can you elaborate in terms of java ?? Or  can you make me understand both ?

Comment: @Sanjay-Dev i suggest you read the concept `OOP` there are many site teach about the concept.

Answer (score 2):

String s=new String ("test")  >> Will always create a new instance.

String s="test" >> If the String literal "***test***" is already present in string pool ( Java Heap) , reference ***s*** will point to this literal, No new instance will be created.
Please refer below image for more clarity.

[image]

Comment: And, `s1.equals(s3)` returns a `true`

Answer (score 1):

> Integer i=new Integer(10);
>
> Integer i=10;
>
> What is the difference ?

```
Integer i = new Integer(10);
```

The above statement constructs a newly created `Integer` object that represents the specified `int` value. `i` is a reference variable, and new `Integer(10)` creates an object of type `Integer` with a value of `int 10`, and assigns this object reference to the variable `i`.

More info about Integer at: [java.lang.Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)

Consider the statement:

```
Integer i = 10;
```

The result is same as that of the earlier construct; an integer wrapper object is created. It is just a convenience syntax. For example, see the following code:

```
Integer i = new Integer(10);
System.out.println(++i); // this prints 11
```

There is no such syntax as `++` in the `java.lang.Integer` class definition. What is happening here?

The statement `++i`, unboxes the `Integer` to an `int`, performs the `++` operation on the `int` value, and then boxes it back - which results in an object integer with the `int` value incremented from `10` to `11`. This feature is called **Autoboxing**; note that this feature was introduced in Java 5.

NOTE: The above clarification doesn't apply to the question asked in this post regarding the `String` class.

Comment: For additional info see notes from Oracle's website on [Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), [Number classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html) and [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).